# Выполнение скриптов в поле input

Tags: html5, javascript, html, веб-программирование

На странице есть поле `input`. При вводе туда строчки типа:

```
<script> alert('dd'); </script>
```

этот скрипт выполняется. Как сделать так чтобы этого не происходило. Тоже самое интересно про `php` если я в веду туда какой нибудь `php` скрипт строчка запишется в базу а при обновлении страницы выполнится. Как зделать так чтобы было неважно что вводить в поле `input`  чтобы все то что там есть всегда было как простой текст?

Comment: http://php.net/manual/ru/function.htmlentities.php ? только я не понял, почему у вас вдруг из input скрипты выполняются ? вы добавляете этот текст в документ ?

Comment: добавлю еще `strip_tags()` если конечно на сервере используется PHP

Comment: Ну эти inputs это строчки меню и текст в них можно редактировать. Соответственно после редактирования текст записывается в базу.

Comment: Спасибо, просветили) вам дали пути решения, используйте! Перед записью в  БД проверять данные нужно!

Comment: я не хочу как то менять в веденную строчку удаляя теги или заменяя их на что нибудь. Я хочу чтобы в поле input ничего не выполнялось. Есть ли такая возможность?

Comment: @Alexey Borozdin: Просто так ничего из поля input не выполняется. Вы где-то добавляете его содержимое в документ.

Comment: вам нужно менять не текст введенный в базу, а текст выводимый программой.

Comment: Перед вставкой в базу данных удаляйте тег script и его содержимое, а также проверяйте ссылки

Comment: @eicto лучше перед добавлением в БД :) а то еще инъекцию отправят через инпут )